# SQL Server 2005 - optimizing stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have 2 stored procedures (`sp1` and `sp2`) in SQL Server 2005 with the same sql script (no diff at all but the name).

When I try to execute `sp1` it returns more than 3000 rows as result, in 0-1 secs.
But when I run `sp2` it will return those 3000 rows in 10 seconds.

Would like to know is there any tool/command/anything which can set a specific stored procedure to optimize well?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you executing those in the same database? Or different ones? Sounds like it's two separate databases, and the second database has e.g. outdated statistics or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server saves "plans" of how to execute code.

If a stored procedure is run against a small subset of data it will optimize for a small dataset. The opposite is true for a large dataset.

Theres a nice `OPTIMIZE FOR` feature in 2008 but in 2005 you are stuck with `WITH RECOMPILE`. This means it will be recompiled each time it is run, which, in some cases is most optimal!

Comment: Thanks for info.  running these 2 procs on Sql Server 2005.