# Stored procedure to create a table using a comma delimited list of column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am running SQL Server 2005. 
I would like to create a stored procedure that would create a table with the name table1 and using a passed list of comma delimited values, use each element in that list as the column name.

So basically it would be like sp_procedurename(col1,col2,col3)

would create table1 with columns col1, col2 and col3
(and if they could all be varchar(max) that would be great too.

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings? Like `sp_procedurename('table1', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3')` or `sp_procedurename('col1,col2,col3')`

Comment: Yes, but you can hardcode table1. The list can just be the column names.

Comment: In other words I'd like to be able to feed the procedure a list of whatever column names I want and have it build a table on the fly.

Comment: You can find hundreds of implementations of splitting a string with SQL - there are lots of ways to do it, some simple like looping through each character, and some more complex with fancy algorithms, but they all work. From there, it's just a matter of building a dynamic SQL statement and executing it. Security should be a big concern here since you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Joe I don't think you really need to split here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep, good point. I didn't think about replacing the commas directly like you've got it in your answer.

Comment: I don't know why I was flagged. It was a clearly articulated question about sql server 2005 that netted a valid solution. I have seen questions like this mine throughout this site with no code examples. For eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243254/sql-server-2005-optimizing-stored-procedures?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever -- do not use sp_ prefix!
  @tablename SYSNAME,
  @column_list VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '
    (
      [' + REPLACE(@column_list, ',', '] VARCHAR(MAX),
      [')
      + '] VARCHAR(MAX)
    );';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

This doesn't do any error-handling, such as if `@tablename` already exists, nor does it do anything at all to protect you from SQL injection. If this comma-separated list of column names it typed in by a user, proceed with extreme caution.

Oh and [here's why you shouldn't use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: How would you call that? crt_tbl('looper' 'col1,col2,col3') doesnt work.

Comment: Ahh i see. crt_tbl looper,'col1,col2,col3'

Comment: `EXEC dbo.whatever @tablename = N'looper', @column_list = 'col1,col2,col3';`

Comment: crt_tbl? Is typing so hard that you need to make your names that terse and unreadable (and for many people harder to type) just to avoid vowels?

Comment: Mr. Bertrand, I just picked a quick name for testing purposes. Thank you for your solution.